# Starting an FSM through another FSM multiple times

Tags: vhdl, state-machine

I need help for my VHDL design. If anyone out there havae a look at, I'll appreciate it. After several days I didn't achieve to find the wrong point.

**The purpose of the design:
I have a finite state machine (FSM2) and want to process it multiple times (for now 2 times). Thus I thought to use another Finite st. Mach. (FSM1). But an FSM is not necessary. The conditions I want them to work is described below.**

Thanks in advance.

---

flag0=1 starts FSM1

FSM1 generates flag1=1 which starts another process to generate a definite width pulse (P) to start FSM2. P=0 much before flag2 and resets flag1=0.

FSM2 generates  flag2=1 during operation. In the end it goes back to flag2=0
flag2=0 change state of FSM1 ST1 to ST2 , flag1=1, and FSM2 process again through P, flag2=0 again

FSM1 goes back to ST0 flag1=0

Without FSM1 whole design process correct.

flag0 and flag 2 is fine, but flag 1 doesn't drive correct!

---

FSM1:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL ;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Data_Organiser is
Port ( clk                          : IN  STD_LOGIC ;
       DO_Period_Flag               : IN  STD_LOGIC ;                       
       DO_Data_Sent_progress_flag   : IN  STD_LOGIC ;                       
       DO_DATA                      : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0) ;  
       DO_Data_Part                 : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0) ;   
       DO_Set_flag                  : OUT STD_LOGIC ;                          
       state_info   : out std_logic_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0) );
end Data_Organiser;

architecture Behavioral of Data_Organiser is

type   STATES is (ST_IDLE, ST_FIRST_PART, ST_SECOND_PART, ST_CLEANUP);
signal NEXT_STATE : STATES := ST_IDLE;

signal s_clk            : STD_LOGIC ;
signal s_DO_DATA        : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0) ;
signal s_DO_Data_Part   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0) ;
signal s_DO_Period_Flag : STD_LOGIC ;
signal s_DO_Data_Sent_progress_flag : STD_LOGIC ;

signal s_DO_Set_flag : STD_LOGIC ; 

begin

s_clk <= clk ;

s_DO_Period_Flag   <= DO_Period_Flag ;
s_DO_Data_Sent_progress_flag <= DO_Data_Sent_progress_flag ;
s_DO_DATA          <= DO_DATA ;   

FSM_SERIAL : process (s_clk, s_DO_DATA,s_DO_Period_Flag,s_DO_Data_Sent_progress_flag)
begin
    if (rising_edge(s_clk)) then
        case NEXT_STATE is                
            when ST_IDLE =>                    
                if ( s_DO_Period_Flag = '1' ) AND ( s_DO_Data_Sent_progress_flag = '0' ) then                         
                    NEXT_STATE      <= ST_FIRST_PART ;
                else
                    NEXT_STATE      <= ST_IDLE ;
                    s_DO_Set_flag   <= '0' ;
                end if ;

            when ST_FIRST_PART =>                    
                s_DO_Data_Part  <= "01110111"; 
                s_DO_Set_flag   <= '1' ;                   
                if ( s_DO_Period_Flag = '0' ) AND ( s_DO_Data_Sent_progress_flag = '0' ) then 
                    NEXT_STATE <= ST_SECOND_PART ;
                else
                    s_DO_Set_flag   <= '0' ;
                    NEXT_STATE      <= ST_FIRST_PART ; 
                end if ;

            when ST_SECOND_PART =>
                s_DO_Data_Part <= "01000100" ;           
                s_DO_Set_flag  <= '1' ;                    
                if ( s_DO_Data_Sent_progress_flag = '0' ) then
                    NEXT_STATE <= ST_CLEANUP ;
                else
                    s_DO_Set_flag   <= '0' ;
                    NEXT_STATE      <= ST_SECOND_PART ;
                end if ;

            when ST_CLEANUP  =>                    
                s_DO_Data_Part  <= X"00";
                NEXT_STATE      <= ST_IDLE ;                    
            when others =>
                s_DO_Set_flag   <= '0' ;
                NEXT_STATE      <= ST_IDLE ;

        end case;
    end if;
end process FSM_SERIAL ;

DO_Data_Part  <= s_DO_Data_Part ;
DO_Set_flag   <= s_DO_Set_flag ;

end Behavioral;
```

FSM2:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL ;

entity Serial_Link is
generic(Baud_Match_Num  : integer := 1085 );
port (  clk             : IN  STD_LOGIC  ;     -- 125 MHz
        SL_DATA         : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0) ;
        SL_DATA_REQUEST : IN  STD_LOGIC ; 
        SL_START_BIT    : OUT STD_LOGIC ;
        SL_DATA_SERIAL  : OUT STD_LOGIC ;
        SL_STOP_BIT     : OUT STD_LOGIC ;
        SL_DATA_SENT_PROGRESS_FLAG : OUT STD_LOGIC); 
end Serial_Link;

architecture Behavioral of Serial_Link is    
signal s_clk    :   STD_LOGIC; 
type   STATES is (ST_IDLE, ST_START_BIT, ST_DATA_BITS, ST_STOP_BIT, ST_CLEANUP);
signal NEXT_STATE : STATES := ST_IDLE;  

signal Bit_Keep_Count : integer range 0 to Baud_Match_Num-1 := 0;
signal Bit_index      : integer range 0 to 7 := 0;  -- 8 Bits Total
signal s_SL_DATA      : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin

s_clk  <= clk ;    

FSM_SERIAL : process (s_clk,SL_DATA)
begin
    if (rising_edge(s_clk)) then
        case NEXT_STATE is  -- TRANSMISSION STARTS IN " IDLE " MODE

            when ST_IDLE =>
                SL_START_BIT   <= '1';
                SL_DATA_SERIAL <= '1'; 
                SL_STOP_BIT    <= '0';
                Bit_Keep_Count <=  0 ;
                Bit_index      <=  0 ;

                if SL_DATA_REQUEST = '1' then
                    s_SL_DATA  <= SL_DATA;
                    NEXT_STATE <= ST_START_BIT;
                    SL_DATA_SENT_PROGRESS_FLAG <= '1' ;   -- DATA SENDING STARTED     : FLAG --> 1
                else
                    NEXT_STATE <= ST_IDLE;
                    SL_DATA_SENT_PROGRESS_FLAG <= '0' ;   -- DATA SENDING NOT STARTED : FLAG --> 0
                end if;

            when ST_START_BIT =>
                SL_DATA_SERIAL <= '0'; -- START BIT IN SERIAL DATA !!!

                if Bit_Keep_Count < Baud_Match_Num-1 then 
                    Bit_Keep_Count <= Bit_Keep_Count + 1;
                    NEXT_STATE     <= ST_START_BIT;
                    SL_START_BIT   <= '0';
                else                            
                    Bit_Keep_Count <= 0;
                    NEXT_STATE     <= ST_DATA_BITS;
                    SL_START_BIT   <= '1';
                end if;

            when ST_DATA_BITS =>
                SL_DATA_SERIAL <= s_SL_DATA(Bit_index);

                if  Bit_Keep_Count < Baud_Match_Num-1 then
                    Bit_Keep_Count <= Bit_Keep_Count + 1  ;
                    NEXT_STATE     <= ST_DATA_BITS     ;
                else
                    Bit_Keep_Count <= 0 ;

                    if Bit_index < 7 then
                        Bit_index  <= Bit_index + 1;
                        NEXT_STATE <= ST_DATA_BITS ;
                    else
                        Bit_index  <= 0  ;
                        NEXT_STATE <= ST_STOP_BIT  ;
                    end if;
                end if;

            when ST_STOP_BIT  =>
                SL_DATA_SERIAL <= '1' ;     -- STOP BIT IN SERIAL DATA

                if  Bit_Keep_Count < Baud_Match_Num-1 then
                    Bit_Keep_Count <= Bit_Keep_Count + 1   ;
                    NEXT_STATE     <= ST_STOP_BIT  ;
                    SL_STOP_BIT    <= '1';
                else                        
                    Bit_Keep_Count <= 0   ;
                    NEXT_STATE     <= ST_CLEANUP  ;
                    SL_STOP_BIT    <= '0' ;
                end if;

            when ST_CLEANUP =>
                SL_DATA_SENT_PROGRESS_FLAG <= '0' ; -- DATA SENDING FINISHED: FLAG --> 0
                NEXT_STATE   <= ST_IDLE ;

            when others =>
                NEXT_STATE <= ST_IDLE ;

        end case;
    end if;
end process FSM_SERIAL ;


end Behavioral ;
```

Comment: Where do you have the failure? Under simulation or after implementation? Why you don't use variables inside the process? How is the port map between the two FSMs? You are talking about flag1, where is flag1 in the code?

Comment: Show your test bench please. That way we can easily reproduce your error.